# Quick way to move items from inventory to chest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim when I wanted to move stuff from one chest to another. It takes ages to get all items one by one into a chest. Is there a way to put all of my stuff from one section (books,misc,etc) to chest on Xbox 360?

Comment: you can take every item, or one stack of arrows etc, but afaik you cant select groups of similar items, unfortunately. If you had the PC version it MAY have been possible through mods, but even then I do not know of such a mod.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're able to take all items from a chest to your inventory by pressing X, but there's no way to do the opposite. You have to do it one by one. Mods won't work because you're on Xbox. I don't think there's any way to move items quickly from inventory to chest.

Comment: Mashing the button and getting those thumb muscles into shape is about the only option.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way to move more than one item from yourself to a container or follower all at once.

Comment: But is there a way to put all your items into a chest?

Comment: @PiotrStokowski All of your items is a group of items, so no.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer To be clear, I would interpret a "group" of items as one of the item tabs: armor, weapons, etc. The answer is still no, of course, but the phrasing could be clearer.